# Problema con tooltip Bootstrap al eliminar instancia y crear otra

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, tooltip

Tengo un panel de filtros con varios *inputs*, si algunos de estos input no pasa una regla de validación se le va a instanciar un *tooltip* para señalar el error.

El problema es cuando por ejemplo tengo un input con el tooltip ya instanciado, necesito *cambiar el texto* de este tooltip porque se dió otro tipo de error, entonces yo hago un *destroy* e instancío nuevamente el toolip.

```
$('#input').tooltip('destroy');  
$('#input').tooltip({ title: 'texto nuevo'})
```

Lo que pasa cuando hago ésto, es que solamente destruye el tooltip pero no crea la nueva instancia, entonces queda todo en la nada.

Qué podría hacer en este caso?

Comment: Por favor, agrega un __[mcve]__ que permita revisar el error que comentas.

Answer (score 1):

la respuesta a tu pregunta sería esta:
validacionFallida es una clase que estoy aplicando a todos los campos de entrada que también tienen tooltips aplicados a ellos.

```
$('.validacionFallida').each(function (index) {
    $(this).removeData('tooltip');
});

$('.tooltip').remove();
```

He probado varias maneras diferentes, y esta fue la única combinación que me permitió agregar tooltips después de la eliminación, sin impedir que las nuevas herramientas funcionen correctamente.

El .removeData permite que la información sobre tooltips se vuelva a vincular en el futuro.

[bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap)[tooltip](/questions/tagged/tooltip)